# Extract remaining Sub-Dataframe. I Have Main Dataframe and 3 Sub Dataframe (extracted from Main Dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Main Dataframe **Test** with a column **Data** with multiple Datatypes as follows

```
Data
1  
2  
3  
4  
ABCDE  
VWXYZ  
ABC6328XZ  
YSGA72IAJ22
```

and performed two tasks into the column Data

**1) Extracted Purely Text Fields (so got ABCDE, VWXYZ)**

```
Texter = Test[Test['Data'].str.isalpha()==True]
```

**2) Extracted Purely Numeric Fields (so got 1,2,3,4)**

```
Number1 = pd.to_numeric(Test['Data'], errors='coerce')
```

Now I am looking to Extract the remaining Dataframe (i.e. ABC6328XZ , YSGA72IAJ22)

so i Tried

```
Remaining = Test[~[Texter,Number1]]
```

Its throwing the following error
bad operand type for unary ~: 'list'

**Please note that I have gone through many posts on bad operand type for unary ~ 'list' but don't know how to proceed with my problem so would appreciate if I can get an answer**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
Remaining = Test.drop(Texter.index.union(Number1.dropna().index))
```

Or save and reuse the masks:

```
m1 = Test['Data'].str.isalpha()
Texter = Test[m1]

Number1 = pd.to_numeric(Test['Data'], errors='coerce')

Remaining = Test[(~m1) & Number1.isna()]
```

Output:

```
          Data
6    ABC6328XZ
7  YSGA72IAJ22
```